# SQL Server EXPRESS: Error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified after setup

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, sql-server-express

(C#/ .Net Framework4.0 / VS2017).
made a c# windows form with sqlcon expressconnection database,but rly not sure how to create a setup for other client...

i have made a windows form application with a database with sqlconnection in it. im using advance installer to create a setup so i can put the .mdf and .idf files with prerequsites easily.

added connection string as:

```
 public static class DAL
    {
        public static DataTable ExecSP(string spName, List<SqlParameter> sqlParams = null)
        {
            string strConnect = "Server=PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyLoginApp;Trusted_Connection=True;";     
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            //Connect to the database
            conn = new SqlConnection(strConnect);
            conn.Open();

            //Build an sql command / query
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray());

            //Execute command
            SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //fill datatable with the results
            dt.Load(dr);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            //No matter what happends this will run
            conn.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

When it trying to execute the following code:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
        sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("Username", TxtUsername.Text));
        sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("Password", txtPassword.Text));

        DataTable dtLoginResults = DAL.ExecSP("ValidateLogin", sqlParams);

        string eUser;
        string ePass;
        eUser = TxtUsername.Text;
        ePass = txtPassword.Text;


        if (dtLoginResults.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            //We know login is valid
            string user = dtLoginResults.Rows[0]["Username"].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(user + " Berhasil Masuk!");
            this.Hide();
            ListMeja lm = new ListMeja();
            lm.ShowDialog();
        }     
         else
        {
            //invalid login
            MessageBox.Show("Password Salah");
        }    
    }
```

gets an error popup window in other client after run the .exe program

> Unhandled exception has occured in your application. if you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and and attempt to continue. A network -related or instance-specific error occured while establish a connection to SQL server.The server was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.  (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified).

what im doing wrong here ?

Comment: sql express is limited connections and by default I think doesnt set itself well for remote connections, did you check its setup?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to Connect SQL Server With SSMS from  Your system.
After Successfully Login Please Edit your  `string strConnect = "Server=PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyLoginApp;Trusted_Connection=True;";` connection string as per SSMS Connected.

Answer (score 0):

well.. this is the solution

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS;" +
         @"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyLoginApp.mdf;Integrated Security = True;User Instance=True");
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```